# Reindexing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a dataFrame from a html file using read_html(). After initial load I decided to use one of my rows as header.

```
df = pd.read_html('http://www.....')[0]  # Read from html file
df.columns = df.iloc[1]  # Use 1th row as header
df = df[2:]  # Removing first two rows including the header row
df.reset_index(drop=True)  # reindexing
```

After all this my dataFrame looks something like this

```
1   RK             PLAYER TEAM  GP   G   A PTS +/- PIM PTS/G  SOG   PCT GWG  \
0    1     Jamie Benn, LW  DAL  82  35  52  87   1  64  1.06  253  13.8   6   
1    2    John Tavares, C  NYI  82  38  48  86   5  46  1.05  278  13.7   8   
2    3   Sidney Crosby, C  PIT  77  28  56  84   5  47  1.09  237  11.8   3   
3    4  Alex Ovechkin, LW  WSH  81  53  28  81  10  58  1.00  395  13.4  11   
4  NaN  Jakub Voracek, RW  PHI  82  22  59  81   1  78  0.99  221  10.0   3
```

So, as you can see it is having value **1** on top of the row index. It obtained this value while I used **df.columns = df.iloc[1]**, where 1 is the row index number.

Desired dataframe should look something like this.

```
    RK             PLAYER TEAM  GP   G   A PTS +/- PIM PTS/G  SOG   PCT GWG  \
0    1     Jamie Benn, LW  DAL  82  35  52  87   1  64  1.06  253  13.8   6   
1    2    John Tavares, C  NYI  82  38  48  86   5  46  1.05  278  13.7   8   
2    3   Sidney Crosby, C  PIT  77  28  56  84   5  47  1.09  237  11.8   3   
3    4  Alex Ovechkin, LW  WSH  81  53  28  81  10  58  1.00  395  13.4  11   
4  NaN  Jakub Voracek, RW  PHI  82  22  59  81   1  78  0.99  221  10.0   3
```

can anyone please suggest me how do I make this happen?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing `headers=0` to `pd.read_html`?

Comment: is your 'index' col with 1 above it considered a column by pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign the column to a pd.Series, you will also inherit the Series name. If the Series comes from a DataFrame row, as in your case, the Series name is the same as its original index (1 in your case). You can reset the name by adding the line `df.columns.name = None` before you print the dataframe result

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks a ton...:)